# Inner or Outer left Join

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm having difficulty modifying a script for this situation and wondering if someone maybe able to help:

I have an `address` table and a `phone` table both sharing the same column called  `id_number`. So `id_number = 2` on both tables refers to the same entity. Address and phone information used to be stored in one table (the `address` table) but it is now split into `address` and `phone` tables since we moved to Oracle 11g.

There is a 3rd table called `both_ids`. This table also has an `id_number` column in addition to an `other_ids` column storing `SSN` and some other ids.

Before the table was split into `address` and `phone` tables, I had this script:
(Written in Sybase)

```
INSERT INTO sometable_3 (          
SELECT a.id_number, a.other_id, 
       NVL(a1.addr_type_code,0)      home_addr_type_code,             
       NVL(a1.addr_status_code,0)    home_addr_status_code,             
       NVL(a1.addr_pref_ind,0)      home_addr_pref_ind,             
       NVL(a1.street1,0)             home_street1,             
       NVL(a1.street2,0)              home_street2,             
       NVL(a1.street3,0)              home_street3,             
       NVL(a1.city,0)                 home_city,             
       NVL(a1.state_code,0)           home_state_code,             
       NVL(a1.zipcode,0)              home_zipcode,             
       NVL(a1.zip_suffix,0)           home_zip_suffix,             
       NVL(a1.telephone_status_code,0) home_phone_status,             
       NVL(a1.area_code,0)             home_area_code,             
       NVL(a1.telephone_number,0)      home_phone_number,             
       NVL(a1.extension,0)             home_phone_extension,             
       NVL(a1.date_modified,'')      home_date_modified               
 FROM both_ids a, address a1          
 WHERE a.id_number = a1.id_number(+) 
 AND a1.addr_type_code = 'H');
```

Now that we moved to Oracle 11g, the address and phone information are split.

**How can I modify the above script to generate the same result in Oracle 11g?**

Do I have to first do INNER JOIN between address and phone tables and then do a LEFT OUTER JOIN to both_ids?

I tried the following and it did not work:

```
Insert Into..
  select ...
    FROM a1. address
      INNER JOIN t.Phone ON a1.id_number = t.id_number
      LEFT OUTER JOIN both_ids a ON a.id_number = a1.id_number
    WHERE a1.adrr_type_code = 'H'
```

Comment: Do you expect a given id_number to always be present in all three tables, two or only one of them?

Comment: a given id_number should always be present in the address and phone tables. If a given id_number is present in address then it should also be present in phone table unless this entity does not have a phone. On both_ids table on the other hand this given id_number may or may not present

Comment: Ok, your joining looks ok then, what doesn't work? An error or wrong results?

Comment: Corretion: a given id_number should always be present in both address and phone table even when the entity does not have a phone in which case the id_number is present in phone table but has a blank phone value. For both_ids table, this given id_number may or may not present

Comment: I got an error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 16 : Line 19 refers to this:  AND   LEFT OUTER JOIN tt_gl_both_ids a

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your query. You wrote in comment below that your query is:

```
 ..
 FROM address a1 JOIN telephone t ON a1.id_number = t.id_number
 AND RIGHT OUTER JOIN tt_gl_both_ids a ON a.id_number = a1.id_number
 WHERE
 ..
```

Throw out `AND` and it will work. Also, replace right outer join with left outer join, since that's what you're trying to achieve (again, based on comments you wrote).

Comment: I thought WHERE a.id_number = a1.id_number(+) represents an Outer Left Join. Am I wrong? http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/11971;pt=13175

Comment: @user1557856 its a Right outer join.

Comment: Even when I used Right Join I still get the same error:ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 17: line 19 being : AND   RIGHT OUTER JOIN tt_gl_both_ids a

Comment: Please post complete query that you perform, I don't see `AND` in your query at the moment.

Comment: I can't paste the whole query, too many char.The Top portion is the same as the one I posted on my question, only the join part is different:     FROM  address a1 JOIN telephone t
     ON    a1.id_number = t.id_number
     AND   RIGHT OUTER JOIN tt_gl_both_ids a
     ON    a.id_number = a1.id_number
     WHERE a1.addr_type_code = 'H'